# sending live meeting request to outlook calendar using c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I had created a method that send a meeting request to outlook calendar , now i need to send a live meeting request to the outlook calendar , anybody has an idea on how to do that.

here down is the method body that i am using to create the outlook Calendar request

```
string startTime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
            string endTime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(endTime).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");


            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(mailfrom);
            msg.From = from;

            foreach (var emailto in emailtoList)
            {
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailto);
                msg.To.Add(to);
            }
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = emailbody;

            #region Calender Request
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");

            //PRODID: identifier for the product that created the Calendar object
            str.AppendLine("PRODID:-// //Outlook MIMEDIR//EN");
            str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");

            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", startTime1));//TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc("BeginTime").ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", endTime1));//TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc("EndTime").ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("LOCATION: {0}", location));

            // UID should be unique.
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));

            str.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
            str.AppendLine("ACTION:Accept");
            str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
            str.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY");
            str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

            str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
            System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
            ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
            ct.Parameters.Add("name", "meeting.ics");
            AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), ct);
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
            #endregion

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.outlook.com", 587);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailfrom, password);
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
```